# Backup and Restore with Holo ( ADB ) from N4 to another N4 - some questions

Tags: adb, backup

I am soon receiving a replacement device for my Nexus 4, that got some problems charging now and then.

Some questions regarding Holo Backup:

1. It shall be no problem to restore a "Backup all without system apps" and sdcard from N4 to N4 both running the exact same firmware and stuff, right?
2. Does this option also backups alarms, ringtones set for certain things and sdcard0?
3. Anyway to save my widgets and stuff placed on default homescreen?

//EDIT

my replacement just arrived. Gonna answer these questions soon.

Answer (score 0):

Restore via Holo Backup didnt worked at all. Nothing happened on my phone no matter what kind of backup i tried to restore.

Restore via adb from commandoline worked... well not the full backup!! it stucked at an app called "Tasks".

But backup only from app and system data worked fine! So i just let google restore all my apps.

Apps and Folders on the Homescreen were restored. eMail ringtone too (hangouts sms not).
alarms were also restored.

I just pulled and pushed my whole sdcard0 folder manually.